# Register user with HWIOAuthBundle without Register Form

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3, hwioauthbundle

I am using `HWIOAuthBundle` with `FOSUserBundle` and it's work fine.

My probleme is : When The User choose to connect with Facebook for exemple, the page it redirects me to the Facebook Accounts, authorizes and returns back to the register form with filled data.

How can I make a auto Register with ommiting register form ?